# Filter data on basis on PHP timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this

```
|---------|--------------------|---------------------|-------------------|
|   id    |   first_name       |    last_name        |     timestamp     |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    1    |     Saswat         |      Routroy        |    12098345765    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    2    |     Tuhin          |       Paul          |    12098565765    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    3    |     Tuhina         |       Paul          |    12098565455    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    4    |     Sabina         |       Khatun        |    12098578955    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    5    |     Shajid         |       Daruwala      |    12098598455    |
|________________________________________________________________________|
```

Here the timestamp field is having value in this method

```
$timestamp = time();
```

and hence inserted into the database...

Now, i need to filter data on this options

```
today,
yesterday,
last seven day,
this month.
```

here's my script

```
$dt_table = "td_user";
    $arr_result = array();
    $sql = "SELECT id,timestamp,first,last,company_name,company_size FROM td_user LIMIT $start_row , $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $tot_data = 0;


    if($time_type == "today")
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
            $date = date('Y-m-d', $data_timestamp);
            $today = date('Y-m-d');
            if ($date == $today) 
            {
                $arr_result[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    else if($time_type == "yesterday")
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data_timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
            $midnightYes = strtotime("midnight yesterday");
            $midnightToday = strtotime("midnight today");
            if ($data_timestamp > $midnightToday) 
            {
                //today
            } 
            else if($data_timestamp > $midnightYes && $data_timestamp < $midnightToday) 
            {
                $arr_result[] = $row;
            }
        }
    }
    else if($time_type == "last_seven_day")
    {

    }
    else if($time_type == "last_month")
    {

    }
```

Now, i have successfully retrieved data from today and yesterday... but how to get data from `last seven days` and `this month`??

Comment: `strtotime('-7 days')` `strtotime('-1 month')`, and you can still do things like `strtotime('-1 month midnight')` if needed

Answer (score 1):

You have, if you want to use strtotime :

```
$last = strtotime('last week');
$month = strtotime('this month');
```

You have documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: $month = strtotime('this month'); its some error i think

Comment: The keyword month is in the documentation.. You can also use other keyword for month, you have multiple possibilities

Answer (score 0):

use DATE and CURDATE()

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()

I guess using DATE still uses INDEX.

[see the execution plan on the DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72440/2)